# Making a relative div fixed to the top of the screen

Tags: html, css

I need to make `#outer1` to be fixed at the top of screen, but I cannot do it without messing up the current positions. I cannot just make `#outer1` fixed, as I need it to be relative, because the divs on the insides need to be absolute positioned. What should I do instead to make `#outer1` to be fixed at the top of the screen?

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#outer1 {
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
#outer2 {
  height: 900px;
}
#left {
  display: inline-block;
}
#right {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='outer1'>
  <div id='left'>Left</div>
  <div id='right'>Right</div>
</div>

<div id='outer2'></div>
```

Comment: Can't you just use `float:right;` on the `#right` div and then fix the position of `#outer1`

Comment: Pretty hard for anyone to make suggestions based on some very simple layout information given and no visual demo. Also...the problem of the absolute elements doesn't really make sense. Why does it matter that they are absolute?

Comment: @Fred-ii- You're right. There was a typo. It was suppose to be #outer1. My fingers just glitched over the number 1. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I cannot just make `#outer` fixed, as I need it to be relative, because the divs on the insides need to be absolute positioned.

Simply because the most common arrangement for absolutely positioned children involves a relatively positioned parent, doesn't mean that's the only way.

The rule for absolutely positioned elements is that their containing block is the [*nearest positioned ancestor*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning). `#outer1` with position fixed is a positioned ancestor, so it qualifies. It's just that 99% of the time people use `position: relative` since that has minimal impact on the parent.

There's no problem using `position: fixed` as a containing block for absolutely positioned children.

From MDN:

> A **positioned element** is an element whose computed position
>   property is either `relative`, `absolute`, `fixed` or `sticky`. *(In other words, anything other than `static`)*
>
> A **relatively positioned element** is an element whose computed
>   position property is `relative`.
>
> An **absolutely positioned element** is an element whose computed
>   position property is `absolute` or `fixed`.
>
> A **stickily positioned element** is an element whose computed
>   position property is `sticky`.
>
> The `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` properties specify the
>   position of positioned elements.
>
> The absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to *nearest
>   positioned ancestor (non static)*. If a positioned ancestor doesn't
>   exist, the initial container is used.
>
> <sub>source:
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position</sub>

Comment: So, you're saying instead of using relative for #outer1, use fixed instead?

Comment: You can use `position: fixed` and the child elements will respect the fixed parent as their containing block (just like with `position: relative`). See this updated fiddle; https://jsfiddle.net/o8yajL8c/

Comment: Do you see the bottom-right corner of #right? See the line that's going outside of the border to the bottom right? Why is that happening?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome in incognito. I'm seeing it in the fiddle. Also, why do we have to add transform to #right, and what does it do?

Comment: It simply tells `#right` to move half its width back into the container. But that's not really important for this question. What really matters is that the `#outer1` is `fixed`, and both `left` and `right` are contained within it. If you remove `fixed`, you'll see the children leave `#outer1`.

Comment: Also, please add width:50% to both #outer1 and #outer2 and see if you see #outer1 overflowing to the right slightly.

Comment: Why is half of #right outside of the container in the first place though?

Comment: Yes with `width: 50%` applied on `#outer1` and `#outer2`, `#outer1` overflows to the right.

Comment: I really don't understand that. Can you explain why that happens? If both divs are exactly the same width, why does one overflow to the right? More specifically, the fixed div? Also, the same thing happens if the width of both are 100%, but it only overflows a little, and it's not too noticeable, so maybe that's why you're not seeing it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101549/discussion-between-michael-b-and-frosty).

Answer (score 1):

You can still have absolutely positioned child elements in a div with `fixed` position, it doesn't have to be specifically relative, it just can't be `static`, the default value for `position`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#outer1 {
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
#outer2 {
  height: 900px;
}
#left {
  display: inline-block;
}
#right {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='outer1'>
  <div id='left'>Left</div>
  <div id='right'>Right</div>
</div>
<div id='outer2'></div>
```