# How to stick fixed elements to the sides of a centered container?

Tags: html, css

I have a centered container and I need to stick two elements to its left and right side, which would act like a background. I can do this simply with `:before` and `:after` elements which would be positioned absolutely with `left: -<element_width>;` and `right: -<element_width>`. Problem is that I need their position to be `fixed` and `fixed` positioning doesn't work relatively to the parent.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9morgwot/).

How can I achieve this? I don't mind new-css tricks which don't work in old browsers.

Comment: Maybe `position: sticky` is an option. See [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32262455/3597276) and [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38812478/3597276) and [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34984452/3597276).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: fixed` and `calc` to achieve that

Check the updated css below

```
.content {
    width: 50%;
    height: 2000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    background: white;
}

.content:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed; //fixed position
    left: calc(50% - 25% - 50px); // used calc to determine the correct position
    background: red;
}
```

**Explanation**
`left: calc(50% - 25% - 50px);`

`50%` is to position the item at the center of the page.

`-25%` is half the value of the parent container which is `50%`

`-50px` is the width of `:before` to move it to the left

**Quick Note:** Most browsers will set the default `left` and `top` positions of a `fixed` position element to be the same `left` and `top` of its parent container, so if you used `position:fixed` without specifying `left` and `top` the fixed element will default to its parent element position

**Edit:** as mentioned in comments above `position:sticky` will also do the trick but it might give some different behaviour on old browsers and mobile devices.